# How to join with results on the same line in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, max, resultset

This is a follow up question to my previous question: [How to get multiple rows of data into different columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41495998/how-to-get-multiple-rows-of-data-into-different-columns)

My query looks very similar to the one provided in the previous question:

```
SELECT AccountID,
   Value1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Value END),
   Value2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Value END),
   Value3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Value END)
FROM
(
SELECT AccountID,
       Value = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), Value), -- Cast GUID as VARCHAR(50) to use MAX() in the outer query.
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY Value)
FROM @myTable
) T
GROUP BY AccountID;
```

I have gotten my query to output the data to one row as follows:

```
AccountID                              Value1                                 Value2                                 Value3
6D68E2C9-4BF8-433B-8BC3-57D87348D034   F0BFA1B1-744A-4DBC-BE27-19D1618D77EA   E22A4B08-40DC-42E5-BC15-72A6912D0D66   A955B30C-5352-4B48-9E96-8A831AFA0751
```

The problem I have now is that I need to get the values from the other data table using the values from Value1, Value2, and Value3 (primary keys in the other table). If I was to join on these values I end up getting three rows again. Do I have to do something similar or use a pivot?

I'll eventually want something along the lines of this:

```
Account Id                              Value1Table.Color    Value2Table.Color    Value3Table.Color   Value1Table.Size    Value2Table.Size 
6D68E2C9-4BF8-433B-8BC3-57D87348D034    Blue                 Red                  Orange              Large             Small
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ As posted your query looks like it should be producing the outcome you are looking for. I suspect however that is not the case. We need some details in order to help.

Comment: Why dont you use JOIN + GROUP BY clauses? would you mind to share your tables?

Answer (score 0):

Do the lookup *before* pivoting:

```
SELECT AccountID,
       Value1 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN Value END),
       Value2 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 2 THEN Value END),
       Value3 = MAX(CASE WHEN RN = 3 THEN Value END)
FROM (SELECT AccountID,
             Value = othertable.color.
             RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountID ORDER BY Value)
      FROM @myTable t JOIN
           othertable ot
           ON ot.value = t.value
     ) T
GROUP BY AccountID;
```

Comment: I think this might work. I'll have to update my question again. I'll be looking for 3-4 columns from each of these tables. Do I just return them all before pivoting?